# Вывод символов в консоли C++

Tags: c++

Имеются различные символы, и нужно выводить их в консоли. Например хочу вывести `─╔══╗╔══╦═══╦═══╦`но вместо этих символов в консоли выводятся знаки вопроса, я так предполагаю, что дело в кодировке, и я попробовал ее изменить, но результата нет. Как можно реализовать вывод различных символов в консоль?

Comment: я так понимаю, необходимо использовать unicode в консоли. Есть куча вариантов как это сделать, например прописать SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);

Comment: А какая платформа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout <<  "\u2554" <<endl;
```

Другой вариант

```
cout << u8"\u2554";
```

На Windows, чтобы произвольные символы выводить в консоль, не смотря на текущую `codepage`, можно использовать `WriteConsoleW()`
Ковыряние с `locale` или `SetConsoleOutputCP()` не помогут с Unicode в общем случае.
На других системах, можно просто utf-8 выводить (предполагая, что терминал использует utf-8)

Либо другая графика по [ссылке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)